# How do I check a specific field in a MongoDB Document using Express & Passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, express-session

I have a NodeJS Web application running and it has express, mongoose, passportjs among other unrelated modules to this question.

There are two types of users and each has their own collection in my database.

1. User
2. Admin

When a User successfully signs in through the login page, they get redirected to "/memberdashboard".
Similarly, when an Admin successfully signs in through the login page, they get redirected to "/admindashboard".

Both collections have a "username" and "password" field.
However in my Admin collection, there is an extra field "isAdmin" which is of type Boolean.

I want to redirect someone who logs in to my website based on whether or not they are admin.

So for example, if userA has {"isAdmin" : true}, they will be redirected to /admindashboard else they will be redirected to /memberdashboard.

Some code that might help explain what I'm trying to achieve.

```
app.get("/memberdashboard", function(req, res) {

    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {

        res.render("memberdashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/member");
    }
});

app.get("/admindashboard", function(req, res) {

    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {

        res.render("admindashboard");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/admin");
    }
});
```

My goal is making use of that

```
if(req.isAuthenticated() && //User is Admin) {
    //redirect to appropriate page
}
```

Hope this was clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik passport populates `req.user` once the user is authenticated. So you could expand your check for `/membershipdashboard` to:

```
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    if (req.user.isAdmin) {
        return res.redirect("/admin");
    }
    res.render("memberdashboard");
} else {
    res.redirect("/member");
}
```

You can do this vice-versa for the `/admindashboard`-route.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. You are right, i can access fields using req.user.fieldName